# Find certain/specific line-breaks while ignoring others

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some SRT data that is coming back with \r and \n tags as line breaks in the middle of each sentence.  How do I find only those \r and \n tags in the middle of the text/sentences and NOT the other ones that signify other line-breaks.

Example source:

```
18
00:00:50,040 --> 00:00:51,890
All the women gather
at the hair salon,

19
00:00:52,080 --> 00:00:56,210
all the mothers and daughters
and they dye their hair orange.
```

Desired output:

```
18
00:00:50,040 --> 00:00:51,890
All the women gather at the hair salon,

19
00:00:52,080 --> 00:00:56,210
all the mothers and daughters and they dye their hair orange.
```

I am absolute crap at regex, but my best guess (to no avail) was something like

> var reg = /[\d\r][a-zA-z0-9\s+]+[\r]/

And then split() on that to remove any \r in the middle of one of the values.  I am sure that is not even close to the right way so...stackoverflow!! :)

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ is your friend as well!

Comment: What if the sentence was `There are 3\rwomen with orange hair.`? How do you distinguish between the line break after the `3` as compared to the line break after the section numbers (or whatever they are)? Can we assume each block is always a section(?) number on a line by itself, then the `00:00:52,080 --> 00:00:56,210` bit on a line by itself, then one or more lines of text (and that's where line breaks need to be removed), then a blank line?

Comment: EXACTLY! Thats why it is so tricky.  But yes, we can assume that the cue line (ie, "18") will always be on its own line AND the time-range will always be on one line.  The only thing that might be on two lines is the text.  Does that help at all???

Answer (score 1):

This will match the line breaks you want to get rid of, capturing the character before and after it, to put those two back in place around a space:

```
var regex = /([a-z,.;:'"])(?:\r\n?|\n)([a-z])/gi;
str = str.replace(regex, '$1 $2');
```

Some things about the regular expression. I used the modifiers `i` and `g` to make it case-insensitive and to find all line breaks in your string instead of stopping after the first one. Also, it assumes that removable line breaks can occur **after** a letter, comma, period, semicolon, colon or single or double quotes and **before** another letter. As @nnnnnn mentioned in a comment above, this will not cover all possible sentences, but it should at least not choke on most punctuation. The line break does have to be a single line break, but it is platform-independent (can be either `\r`, `\n` or `\r\b`). I capture both the character before the line break and the letter after the line break (with parentheses), so I can access them in the replacement string with `$1` and `$2`. That is basically all there is to it.

Comment: Okay, first off.  Thank you.  That stuff is seriously voodoo to me.  And it comes SUPER close but it looks like its killing the character right AFTER the break (off by one).  For example, now "19" looks like this

19
00:00:52,080 --> 00:00:56,210
all the mothers and daughters 
nd they dye their hair orange.

(see how its missing the "a" of and but still has the break?)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I added a capturing group later on and forgot to adjust the replacement. I will edit the answer in a second!

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick:

`/(\d+\r\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\r)([^\r]+)\r([^\r]+)(\r|$)/g`

To make this work with more lines (has to be a set number) then just add more `([^\r]+)\r`'s. (Remember to also add `$`'s to the match replace as so (with 3 lines): `'$1$2 $3 $4\r'`).

## Usage

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(\d+\r\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\r)([^\r]+)\r([^\r]+)(\r|$)/g, '$1$2 $3\r');
```

---

## Limitations

- If there is more than 2 lines of text this won't work.

---

## Example 1

*Works fine!*

**Input:**

```
18
00:00:50,040 --> 00:00:51,890
All the women gather
at the hair salon,

19
00:00:52,080 --> 00:00:56,210
all the mothers and daughters
and they dye their hair orange.
```

**Output:**

```
18
00:00:50,040 --> 00:00:51,890
All the women gather at the hair salon,

19
00:00:52,080 --> 00:00:56,210
all the mothers and daughters and they dye their hair orange
```

---

## Example 2

*Doesn't work; more than 2 lines*

**Input:**

```
18
00:00:50,040 --> 00:00:51,890
All the women gather
at the hair salon,
and they just talk

19
00:00:52,080 --> 00:00:56,210
all the mothers and daughters
and they dye their hair orange.
Except for Maria who dyes it pink.
```

**Output:**

```
18
00:00:50,040 --> 00:00:51,890
All the women gather at the hair salon,
and they just talk

19
00:00:52,080 --> 00:00:56,210
all the mothers and daughters and they dye their hair orange.
Except for Maria who dyes it pink.
```